# How to fill null value in datetime column in python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, missing-data

Sample Data:

```
EmployeeId     city       Datetime
0   001        Mumbai     2015-12-11                       
1   001        Bangalore  2016-02-15
2   002        Pune       2016-01-26
3   002        Mumbai       NaN
4   003        Delhi      2015-04-29
5   003        Mumbai       NaN
6   004        Bangalore    NaN
7   004        Pune       2016-01-25
8   005        Mumbai     2015-12-13
```

Expected output:

```
   EmployeeId         city       Datetime

    0   001        Mumbai     2015-12-11                       
    1   001        Bangalore  2016-02-15
    2   002        Pune       2016-01-26
    3   002        Mumbai     2015-12-16
    4   003        Delhi      2015-04-29
    5   003        Mumbai     2015-12-13
    6   004        Bangalore  2016-01-17
    7   004        Pune       2016-01-25
    8   005        Mumbai     2015-12-13
```

1. How to fill Nan values in the datetime column?
2. Need to consider **City** column to fill the null values in datetime.

From example take the from city and datetime of Mumbai and fill the datetime null value for Mumbai.
and same for other city.

How can we do that?

Comment: can you define average datetime? average relative to what?

Comment: Can you add expected output from sample data?

Comment: Need to fill null values in Datetime column as of my first step @jezrael

Comment: @ManojKumar - Ok, can you add how looks expected output I think DataFrame filled by datetimes without missing values, I am interested about filled numbers.

Comment: Need to consider the datetime of particular city and fill the Nan values in datetime excluding the other cities datetime. @Manakin

Comment: @ManojKumar - all new 3 values are count from data in question? Are you sure? Because not matching.

Comment: Sorry, it's a typo. I didn't consider any formula @jezrael

Comment: ok, so what is logic for create new filled data? Why is filled by `2016-01-17` and not `2000-01-01` ?

Comment: The Date starts from 2015 year and 12 month @jezrael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
pairs = data[["city", "Datetime"]].dropna().to_dict()
fill_values = dict(zip(pairs['city'].values(), pairs['Datetime'].values()))
data.Datetime = data.apply(lambda d: fill_values[d.city] if d.Datetime is np.nan else d.Datetime, axis=1)
print(data)
```

1. Get the city and the datetime and drop all rows with nan values.
2. Convert it to a dict to create next dict element.
3. Create the lookup dict with city as the key and the datetime as value.
4. Iterate over all rows and check if the Datetime has to be replaced.
5. Assign the resulting series/list to the target columns.